# Manager isn't accessible via `Model` instances

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have polymorphic tagging model and I want to create tag_cloud for it,
but when I wanna count related object to tags

```
tags = TaggedItem.objects.all()
# Calculate tag, min and max counts.
min_count = max_count = tags[0].object.objects.count()
```

i get:

```
Manager isn't accessible via Artcle instances
```

tagging.models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=100)
    #.....

class TaggedItem(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    #.....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mistake was issued in first place, Because if I want access to `tags` and *count* them in this situation, I rather to change

```
tags = TaggedItem.objects.all()
# Calculate tag's min and max counts.
min_count = max_count = tags[0].object.objects.count()
```

to:

```
tags = Tag.objects.all()
# Calculate tag, min and max counts.
min_count = max_count = tags[0].taggeditem_set.count()
```

Answer (score 5):

Your are trying to access the manager from a model instance which is not possible. More infos:[Retrieving objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects) (specially the Note).

```
 tags[0].object.objects.count()   \/
         ¨¨¨¨¨¨                   /\
```

rather you can do this (not tested):

```
object_klass = tags[0].object.__class__
min_count = max_count = object_klass.objects.filter(pk=tags[0].object.pk).count()
```

Answer (score 4):

Would it not be easier/cleaner to just add a count method to TaggedItem. Possibly something like below. I'm a bit rusty this code might not work.

```
class TaggedItem(models.Model):
     tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
     content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
     object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
     object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

     def get_object_count():
         return self.object__count #or return self.object.count()
```