# Manager isn't accessible via PermiLayer instances error in django

Tags: django

Why do I get such an error only for PermiLayer model , when the same code/logic works perfectly fine for other models .

My code is this

```
 uperm = PermiLayer()
 perml=uperm.objects.get(pk = num)
```

Ps: I have already tried [Manager isn't accessible via `Model` instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549687/manager-isnt-accessible-via-model-instances) solutions there . But didn;'t work out

Edit:

This is my models

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from maps.models import  Sdr_Layer
from OsmMap.models import OsmLayers
class PermiLayer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    table = models.IntegerField()
    permi = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: can we see the model classes?

Comment: isn't it table = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)

Comment: No . It was causing problems . So I changed it . Though it still stores the table id in there

Comment: Programming by coincidence. Never a great plan.

Comment: http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence

Answer (score 1):

Managers are accessible only via Model Classes, rather than from model instances
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects

why don't you just get it like

```
perml=PermiLayer.objects.get(pk = num)
```

Comment: PermiLayer matching query does not exist.
 I get this as an error .

Comment: what's the type of num? hope it isn't string. Also are you sure you have such row with that "num" id?

Comment: It was a string . Typecasted it to int . But still facing the same problem

Comment: i think you don't have such object with that pk. That's how DoesNotExist error raises.

Comment: Hmm . I think its more of a logical error of how I have designed the model rather than the code error .